# Calloc interacting weird with fgets?

Tags: c, printf, fgets

I have a problem with this code. It should read two numbers and a sentence in this format:

```
no1
no2
sentence
```

and print them like this:

```
no1 no2 sentence
```

Here is the code:

```
scanf("%d", &nrP);
    for (i = 0; i < nrP; i++) {
        com[i].id = i;
        com[i].msg = calloc(256, 1);
        scanf("%d %f", &com[i].no1, &com[i].no2);
        fgets(com[i].msg, sizeof(com[i].msg), stdin);
        printf("%d\n", com[i].id);
        printf("\n%d %.6f ", com[i].no1, com[i].no2);
        printf("%s\n", com[i].msg);
    }
```

I've included the stdio.h and stdlib.h headers and also created the com structure, but decided not to post them here in order to keep it a bit cleaner.

So for this data entry:

```
15
12
I like c
21
23
But it is weird
```

It should print

```
1    
15 12 I like c
2
21 23 But it is weird
```

But it prints

```
1
15 12 I l
2
0 0 ike
```

Any ideas please?
P.S: I am required to allocate the exact memory for every com[i].msg.

Comment: `sizeof(com[i].msg)` is probably the size of a pointer. (but you allocated 256 bytes for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious error is passing the size of pointer `com[i].msg` where the size of the pointed-to block is expected to `fgets`.
(The unread non-whitespace non-digits later make the scanning for numbers choke.)

A second error is missing test for input-errors on both `scanf`-calls and the `fgets`-call.

A third error is the missing check for `calloc`-error.

BTW: Why do you use `calloc` at all, instead of `malloc`? You don't derive any advantage from the zero-initialization performed, as you immediately overwrite it anyway.

```
if(1 != scanf("%d", &nrP)) abort();
for (i = 0; i < nrP; i++) {
    com[i].id = i;
    if(!(com[i].msg = malloc(256))) abort();
    if(2 != scanf("%d %f", &com[i].no1, &com[i].no2)) abort();
    if(!fgets(com[i].msg, 256, stdin)) abort();
    printf("%d\n", com[i].id);
    printf("\n%d %.6f ", com[i].no1, com[i].no2);
    printf("%s\n", com[i].msg);
}
// You might want to replace `abort()` with whatever error-handling you prefer.
```